# Sum of all digits for a given Positive Number

Tags: java, algorithm

**Method return should be like if entered a number, suppose 345, then output should be 3+4+5=12 --> 1+2 = 3.** what i am doing wrong here?

```
public class DigitSum
 {
    int  Sum=0;

    public int compute( int MethParam )
    {
        int rem = MethParam%10; 
        Sum+=rem;        

        MethParam = MethParam/10; 
        if(MethParam>10)
            compute(MethParam);

        return Sum+MethParam;  
    }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DigitSum ds  = new DigitSum();
    System.out.println(ds.compute(435));
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Are you getting wrong output?

Comment: try debugging with the debugger or some print statements.

Comment: Why are you using recursion?

Comment: reducing complexity may be.. imo its better than using for loop for big numbers, as some pal used below.

Comment: please see my answer for shortest code tip..

Comment: @user1508907.. Please see my comment on your shortest code tip.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**O(1) Algo for sum Of digits :**

Taking the modulo 9 of any number will return the sum of digits of that number until a single digit number is obtained.

If the number is a multiple of 9, then the sum will will be 9

one liner :

```
public int sumDigit(int n){
    return (n%9 == 0 && n != 0) ? 9 : n%9;
}
```

Alternate implementation :

```
public int sumDigit(int n){

      int sum = n % 9;
      if(sum == 0){
          if(n > 0)
               return 9;
      }
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify the error as the code is working absolutely fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the trick..dint know that

Comment: This is an awesome solution

Comment: @rahulroc.. Sorry bro. It's fine. So I deleted my comment.

Comment: May be worth adding that the value we're after here is called Digital Root, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root): _The digital root (also repeated digital sum) of a number is the (single digit) value obtained by an iterative process of summing digits, on each iteration using the result from the previous iteration to compute a digit sum. The process continues until a single-digit number is reached._

Comment: This is just plain wrong. sumDigit(77) returns 5 instead of 14. It never works with sums > 9

Comment: The question asks for repeated addition of digits until you get a single digit number. In your example 1+4=5 and so is 77%9=5

Comment: @Lirik (n*9 + (n-1))% 9 == (n-1)%9 . So for 19, n = 2, hence answer is (2-1)%9 i.e. 1 which is 1+9=10 => 1+0=1 and that is the expected answer. What is your doubt ?

Comment: @Lirik You should've looked at the OP's example first. For 345, then output should be 3+4+5=12 --> 1+2 = 3. You need to repeatedly add all digits of the result until you get a single digit

Comment: @Rahul I retract my criticism :).

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is [**digital root**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root). So here's a better solution using the formula from `wiki` page I linked.

**Without Recursion: -**

```
public static int compute( int n ) {
    return n - 9 * ((n - 1) / 9);
}
```

---

And, just in case you want (Which I don't think you would), here's a *one-liner* **(Using Recursion)**: -

```
public static int compute( int n ) {
    return n < 10 ? n : compute(n % 10 + compute(n / 10));
}
```

Comment: +1 it won't get better than that.

Comment: dood one word..that is Dope :)

Comment: can't get better solution than this, without recursion.

Comment: Note for any fellow Googlers that digital root is *not* the same as the sum of digits. Digital root is iterated sum of digits operations.

Answer (score 7):

```
    public int FindSumDigit(int number)
    {
        if (number < 10) return number;
        int sum = 0;
        while (number > 0)
        {
            sum += number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return FindSumDigit(sum);
    }
```

Find my code...
Poon you were not adding the whole digits.. In middle itself u was keep on adding the right most digit.

Comment: +1 Elegant solution. Like it better than mine, and unlike most of the answers here returns the desired result.

Comment: please see my answer for shortest code tip..

Comment: Neater recursive version of this: 
`public static int sum(int n) {
   
   if(n < 10) return n;
   return sum(n / 10) + n%10;
   
  }`

Answer (score 3):

Many wrong answers here. Here's what OP wants:

> Method return should be like if entered a number, suppose 345, then
>   output should be 3+4+5=12 --> 1+2 = 3.

This will do the job:

```
public static int compute(int param) {
    int sum = 0;
    do {
        sum = 0;
        while (param > 0) {
            sum += param % 10;
            param /= 10;
        }
        param = sum;
    } while (sum >= 10);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your method to this, then it gives the requested result:

```
public int compute(int methParam) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; methParam > 10; i++) {
        int currentDigit = methParam % 10;
        methParam = methParam / 10;
        sum = sum + currentDigit;
    }
    if (sum + methParam > 10) {
        return compute(sum + methParam);
    } else {
        return sum + methParam;
    }
}
```

Please note that i moved the declaration of `sum` inside the method, instead of making it a field.

Comment: Ah!! You are increasing too much load. Why that need of `logarithmic computation`? Just iterate till the number is greater than `0`.

Comment: This answer also returns `12` for input `345`, OP wants output to be `3`

Comment: I edited the method to output 3 and removed the logarithmic, it was indeed overkill.

Answer (score 1):

IN your code your are not properly returning values to get call for your recursion method.

```
        if ((MethParam >= 10)){
            return compute(MethParam);
        }else
            return Sum + MethParam;
```

Comment: thanks, but i think it still not fulfilling the O/P like 445 should give 4 instead of 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compute( int param )
{
    int x = param % 10;
    int y = param / 10;

    if (y > 0)
        return x + compute(y);

    return x;
}

public int computeNonRec(int param) {
    int result = 0;
    while (param > 0) {
        result += param % 10;
        param /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public int sumDigit(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            sum += n % 10;
            number = n / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a string solution:

```
public int compute( int MethParam )
{
    int sum = 0; 
    string meth = MethParam.ToString();        

    for (char x in meth) {
        sum += int.Parse(x);
    }
    if (sum >= 10) {
        return compute(sum);
    }
    else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This code is in C# not Java so consider it pseudocode.

Comment: You should mention that it's not Java. Also it doesn't return desired result.

Comment: @jlordo I forgot the recursive call. Now it should return as expected.

Comment: Now it'll return the correct result, but your answer should mention the programming language if it's not the one the OP uses.

Answer (score 0):

just a different approach, may not be as efficient due to involved conversions:

```
private static int getUltimateSum(int input) {
    String inputStr = String.valueOf(input);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++) {
        int digit = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(inputStr.charAt(i)));
        sum += digit;
    }
    if(sum > 9)
        return getUltimateSum(sum);
    else
        return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public class DigitSum {
int  Sum=0;
public int compute( int MethParam )
{
    int rem = MethParam%10; 
    Sum+=rem;        

    MethParam = MethParam/10; 
    if(MethParam>10)
        compute(MethParam);
    else
        Sum+=MethParam;

        if(Sum>=10){
        int temp=Sum;
        Sum=0;
        compute(temp);
    }

         return Sum;  
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    DigitSum ds= new DigitSum();
        System.out.println(ds.compute(435));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried before posting? for input `345` OP wants `3`, you return `12`.

Answer (score 0):

shortest code for this is -

```
int compute(int n){
    while(n > 9){
        n = n - 9;
    }
    return n;
}
```

where n is number for which you want to compute some of its digits.

**EDIT: Efficient for only small numbers, say 3 digit number.**

**EDIT: Tested few answers:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int i = 0x0fefefef;

        long st1 = System.nanoTime();
        int n1 = sumDigit(i);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime() - st1;

        long st2 = System.nanoTime();
        int n2 = FindSumDigit(i);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime() - st2;

        long st3 = System.nanoTime();
        int n3 = compute(i);
        long t3 = System.nanoTime() - st3;

        long st4 = System.nanoTime();
        int n4 = compute1(i);
        long t4 = System.nanoTime() - st4;

        System.out.println("Tested for: "+i);
        System.out.println(n1+": "+t1);
        System.out.println(n2+": "+t2);
        System.out.println(n3+": "+t3);
        System.out.println(n4+": "+t4);
    }

    public static int sumDigit(int n){
      int sum = n % 9;
      if(sum == 0){
          if(n > 0)
               return 9;
      }
      return sum;
    }

    public static int FindSumDigit(int n)
    {
        if (n < 10) return n;
        int sum = 0;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            sum += n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return FindSumDigit(sum);
    }

    public static int compute( int n ) {
        return n - 9 * ((n - 1) / 9);
    }

    public static int compute1(int n){
        while(n > 9){
            n = n - 9;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Here is result for above test:

```
Tested for: 267382767
3: 2432
3: 1621
3: 810
3: 5354519
```

Comment: This is shortest code just for writing. But it may take hell lot of iteration to complete. For e.g. try it for `9999999`. It will take `1111110` iterations.

Comment: True Rohit, this is just another solution with some mathematics logic.

Comment: Rohit, my solution is only efficient if number is less than say 2222, it is not generalized solution for number greater than 2222 in terms of CPU, but if you say number will be less than 999 for sure, my solution will be efficient, I am sure. Because if you go with solution provided by Gaurav, that solution will have overhead of method call stacks and hell lot of time on divisions and modulo operations. I have tested and found my solution efficient compared to Gaurav's solution for number less than 2222, or say only 3 digit number.

Comment: @user1508907.. Hmm. Yeah recursion will not give efficient performance for all input. But we cannot assume that we would get only a certain subset. So, for greater number, which of course we can get, you know what is the drawback of your method. Anyways, for more efficient solution even for greater number, see my answer.

Comment: @RohitJain, +25 for best solution without recursion. Can't get any more efficient than that, :)

Comment: @user1508907.. haha :) Well, you can just give a +1. That would be enough. ;)

Comment: @RohitJain, your code is best one.. given +1, :)

Comment: @user1508907.. Ah! That's nice. Good work with that benchmark work. ;)

Answer (score -1):

use this simple java code I created some tymz ago, this was for adding positive numbers as well as negative numbers:

```
class SumDigit
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int sum, i,a,d;
a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
sum = 0;
for(i=1;i< =10;i++)
{
d = a%10;
a = a/10;
sum=sum + d;
} 
System.out.println("Sum of Digit :"+sum);
}
}
```

Comment: Please. At least bother to format your code.

Comment: it won't even compile. `for(i=1;i< =10;i++)` and won't produce output `3` for input `345`, which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Why this answer is upvoted thrice??

Comment: @Azzy.. Well, I very rarely vote down a post. That you can see from my profile. But your code won't compile. And neither will it give correct result when run. You are iterating 10 times. Why are you sure that you need 10 iterations here? I think down votes are justified here. You improve your answer I'll remove my downvote.