# Sum of all digits for a given Positive Number of type long in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, modulo

I was wondering why the following code solutions based on the **modulo operation** do not work when moving from the `int` type to the `long` type.

For example given `111111111111L` I would like to get returned `12L`.

How can I achieve the same expected behaviour described at the following question (that is working only for int type values)?
[Sum of all digits for a given Positive Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985796/sum-of-all-digits-for-a-given-positive-number)

I am also focused on performance issues so I am looking for an efficient solution.

```
public static long sumTheDigitsVersion1(long inputValue){
    long sum = inputValue % 9L;
        if(sum == 0){
            if(inputValue > 0)
                return 9L;
        }
    return sum;
}

public static long sumTheDigitsVersion2(long inputValue){
    return inputValue - 9L * ((inputValue - 1L) / 9L);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't rely on off-site resources in your question. Link them if you like but always quote the relevant bits in your question.

Comment: Why would you expect `12` as output. That question you linked, finding the [`digital root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root), which reduces the number by summing digits, until you get a single digit. So, for `12` it will again be reduced to `1 + 2 = 3`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight. `111111111111L` can be considered decimal?

Comment: I think it would be easiest to convert the number to a string.  Numbers and especially primitives do not have a length, which is going to be very helpful in achieving the functionality your after.

Comment: @RohitJain I am dealing with huge numbers that can not be contained in `int` types. So for example given a huge number like `111111111111` I would like to get the sum of its digits `12`. I might be not 100% aware of the difference between `int` types and `long` types like ranges etc, however I was expecting a working solution similar to the function I wrote.

Comment: @TPPZ. Then that question you linked has nothing to do with what you want to do. Both has different requirement. Please go through that question again.

Comment: @RohitJain I was confusing 2 different problems, thanks for highlighting it. So let's forget the question I linked, if that's possible. Is there an efficient solution for the problem I am trying to solve? For example given this input `111111111111` I would like to get the sum of its digits i.e. `12`. I would like this solution to work with `long` types. If the answer is yes, which is this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came out with the following solution after some tests with different numbers comparing 3 different functions involving 3 different approaches:

- `toCharArray()` and loops,
- basic mathematical computations and loops,
- recursion.

I compared the 3 different approaches according to their time dimension using `System.nanoTime()`.

```
public static long sumTheDigits(long currentIterationValue){

    long currentDigitValue;
    long sumOutputValue = 0;

    while(currentIterationValue != 0) {
        currentDigitValue = currentIterationValue % 10;
        currentIterationValue = currentIterationValue / 10;
        sumOutputValue = sumOutputValue + currentDigitValue;
    }
    return sumOutputValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution does not work because it's a solution to a different problem, namely:

> *repeatedly* add up the number's digits until you achieve an single-digit result.

In other words, it computes `111111111111` -> `12` -> `3`.

When you think about it, `n % 9` cannot possibly return `12` (which is what you say you're expecting).

Comment: Ok I was confusing 2 different problems, thanks for highlighting it. Now I am still trying to see which is the most efficient way to solve the problem, for example given this input `111111111111` I would like to get the sum of its digits i.e. `12`.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive, efficient solution:

```
public static long digitSum(long n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    return n%10 + digitSum(n/10);
}
```

Comment: It's only efficient if the JVM can turn it into a loop, which it probably can't.

Answer (score 2):

About as efficient as you'll get it:

```
private static final int PART_SIZE = 1000;
private static final int[] digitSums = new int[PART_SIZE];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < digitSums.length; i++) {
        for (int n = i; n != 0; n /= 10) digitSums[i] += n % 10;
    }
}

public static long digitSum(long n) {
    int sum = 0;
    do {
        sum += digitSums[(int)(n % PART_SIZE)];
    } while ((n /= PART_SIZE) != 0);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient option buts its the only one I can think of on the top of my head:

```
public static long getDigitalSum(long n){
    n = Math.abs(n); //This is optional, remove if numbers are always positive. NOTE: Does not filter Long.MIN_VALUE

    char[] nums = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray();
    long sum = 0;

    for(char i:nums){
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i)); //Can use Long.parseLong() too
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Note that `Math.abs(n) == n` for `n = Long.MIN_VALUE`. It would be better to skip over the `-` character, or simply reject negative input with an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @Boann Okay... I did not know that. I was thinking since he wanted efficient, running a if statement per character would probably be very bad. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It doesn't compile either. The return type is `void` and there is no `Integer.parseInt(char)` method.

Comment: @Boann Yeah fixed... Its probably the least efficient yes... but its probably the most straightforward. I did not claim it would be the most efficient solution anyway. I merely posted it as a last resort in case nothing else shows up.