# loop summing digits in the string C

Tags: c

I have a programm which make sum of digits in the string. But I need loop which will do a sum while it is not one cipher number. For example my input is number 12345. Sum is 15 (1+2+3+4+5) and this number 15 must be sum one more time and output must be 6. (5+1). It should be work for any number. Thanks for help.

```
int main() {

    char string[100000];
    int i;
    int sum=0;


    scanf("%s", string);


    for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        sum += (string[i] - '0');
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can `sprintf` the sum into another (or the same) string and do it again, perhaps by moving some of the code into a function.

Comment: Your  array is 100k in size. Don't get used to this practice. If you want an array that big, consider using malloc() and family.

Comment: Someone just did a drive-by **-1** on all answers, and left no comments. :-(

Comment: @abelenky This user has been lurking about for sometime now. I'll reduce the damage by using my votes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
   int n, t, sum = 0, remainder;

   t = n;
   while (t != 0)
   {
      remainder = t % 10;
      sum       = sum + remainder;
      t         = t / 10;
   }

   printf("%d\n", sum);
   return 0;
 }
```

Here n is your old sum.
This is the general idea. Please tailor the code to suite your needs.

Comment: Please don't supply actual code for this type of  "how can I" question.

Comment: Note that `n` is not initialized, so this code is flawed.  The return status is slightly dubious — it would be more sensible if the value of `n` was passed into a function not called `main()`.  For `main()`, you probably need to read and write some values.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = atoi(string);
printf("Sum of digits is %d\n", (!(n%9) && n) ? 9 : n%9);
```

See [Sum of all digits for a given Positive Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985796/sum-of-all-digits-for-a-given-positive-number)  for complete details.

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/Obl9re)

Answer (score 1):

I will write you a code snippet, your task is to understand why it works (hint check what happens modulo 9)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
int main()
{
        char buf[BUFSIZE];
        size_t i;
        int modsum=0;
        if (fgets(buf,BUFSIZE,stdin) == NULL)
        {
                puts("Error reading the string");
                return 1;
        }
        for (i=0;i<BUFSIZE && buf[i]!=0 && buf[i]!='\n';i++)
        {
                if (!isdigit(buf[i]))
                {
                        puts("The string is invalid");
                        return 2;
                }
                modsum=(modsum+(buf[i]-'0'))%9;
        }
        printf("%d\n",modsum?modsum:9);
        return 0;
}
```

This code will work for any number except for 0.